# Как задать нужный treshold на этапе обучения модели?

Tags: python, sklearn

Всем привет,
У меня есть алгоритм:

```
clf = LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Когда я использую этот алгоритм для предсказания вероятностей бинарной классификации `clf.predict(X_test)`, алгоритм использует `treshold=0.5` для определения класса классификации. 
Я могу менять treshold, при использовании `predict_proba`, но мне этот вариант не очень подходит.

Меня интересует, есть ли возможность устанавливать нужное мне значение `treshold` на этапе `fit` (обучения модели)? 
Т. е. например, я хочу, чтобы при treshold>=0.6, предсказывался класс 1, при treshold < 0.6 - класс 2. При чем, все эти классы уже получать после этапа `fit`

Comment: Не понимаю, чего вы хотите добиться, threshold=0.5 это именно преобразование predict_proba в predict и более ничего, на fit это никак не влияет. Само преобразование с нужным вам threshold делается элементарно: y_pred_proba > threshold потом можно из bool в int преобразовать, если нужно

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос:

```
class_distrib = {0:treshold, 1:1-treshold}
clf = LGBMClassifier(class_weight = class_distrib)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Спасибо за ответы